# Unable to display images from a comma separated string

Tags: php

I'm trying to display images from database but unable to show .
Please help me.[image]

My code

```
$id = $_GET['reg_id'];

$sql13    = "select * from contacts where reg_id=" . $id;
$result13 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql13);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result13) > 0) {                                                                                                         
   while($documents = mysqli_fetch_array($result13))
 { ?>
        <li class="make_text1" style="font-size:16px">
        <span class="definition"><b> 
        <?php  if(!empty($documents["name"])){ echo  
        $documents["name"]; }?><br><?php  
        if(!empty($documents["image"])){ 
          $upload_dir = 'uploads/';
          // echo "<img src='uploads/".$documents["image"]."' width='800' height='500'> ";
          echo "<img src='uploads/".$documents["reg_id"]."/".$documents["image"]."' width='800' height='500'> ";

}
```

Comment: Do I see it correctly that the file names are separated by a comma?

Comment: You need to reference the "image" property, not "reg_Id"

Comment: Yes, because every document_type_id has multiple images. I want to upload multiple images for  every document_type_id. @Carl Binalla

Comment: When I remove reg_id , it still doesnot work @Russ J

Comment: You do know that every time you use `$documents["image"]` it gives you the exact value it is stored, which is file names with commas? You still need to separate the file names before using them in the `<img>`

Comment: I will try @Carl Binalla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the values in `$documents["image"]`. Try this:

```
$images = explode(',', $documents["image"]);
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo "<img src='uploads/".$documents["reg_id"]."/$image' width='800' height='500'> ";
}
```

or if you only want do display one of them e.g. the first, something like this:

```
$images = explode(',', $documents["image"]);
echo "<img src='uploads/".$documents["reg_id"]."/".$images[0]."' width='800' height='500'> ";
```

Comment: @Prabina the code was missing a call to `explode` to separate the file names when they are comma separated. I've added that now.